# How to say I may mislead you again?

Tags: conversation, phrase-requests

How to say I may mislead you again:

1. because of my poor English,
2. in a good manner
3. the responsibility is mine (no need to speak out, just let she surely know this).

i.e., I'm afraid of my poor English...

Comment: Btw, _mislead_ is usually used as a synonym of _deceive_, but I'm sure any misunderstandings you might cause would be entirely unintentional. :)

Comment: I agree with @z7sg, I read that title "I may mislead you again", to mean "I may lie to you again".

Comment: @z7sg Yes. unintentional :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to indicate all three in a single sentence, I would say:

> I do apologise in advance if my poor English leads to any misunderstanding.

Comment: F'x any experience in using that sentence? ;)

Comment: The 'do' is unnecessary and makes the sentence feel a bit awkward.

Comment: @JCooper: Very common however, to increase the sincerity of the statement.  Usually added in in front of *apologise*, *sympathise*, etc.

Comment: It's downright charming when we hear the Brits use "do" like that, but to an American speaking to another American it would appear somewhat condescending or theatric.

Comment: I'd leave out "in advance" – it's unnecessary and an imposition.

Comment: @HaL Charming? I have to say, I find it utterly irritating. It’s endemic in messages given over intercoms and speakers in stations and such places in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using "apologize":

> Please excuse my English.

Comment: And if you were really rude "Excuse my French !"

Comment: @MrHen Thanks for another way to express this meaning. but the words is too little. I want she feel my sincerity.

Comment: @Alain: And if you _were_ French, "Please excuse the English."

Comment: If you want to say "please don't judge me based on my poor grammar, then "Please excuse my English" is nice shorthand. But it doesn't convey  concern that the speaker may be misunderstood.

Comment: @dodo, as long as you're working on your English, I think you want "her" to know you are sincere, rather than "she"

Answer (score 2):

You could say "I apologize for any misunderstanding. I am still learning English."

Comment: no, that isn't a English website. it's a girl.

Comment: @dodo: eh? Who said anything about a website?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that response, but it would make a great bumper sticker.

Comment: OMG ROFLMAO whatha

Comment: @Hal what does the 'bumper sticker' mean?

Comment: @dodo: These are bumper stickers in excess: http://www.legendsofamerica.com/photos-ghosts/BumperStickerCar.jpg

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> I'm afraid my English didn't serve me
>   well.  I promise I will work hard on
>   it (e.g. I will be reading EL&U every day).

And, for good measure, just add:

> Please let me know if it ever happens
>   again...

One never knows...

Comment: +1 Girls like 'promise'. and your expression looks like very sincerity.

Comment: what's EL&S ?..

Comment: @dodo I think he meant EL&U: English Language and Usage.  The wee one is typo prone ;)

Comment: Thx @Billare, as usual you can read my mind.  Yes that's EL&U, this forum. @dodo after "Please let me know if it ever happens again...", pause, then "The last thing I want is to hurt you.", pause,  "Believe me".  And you're forgiven till next time.

Answer (score -2):

I will tell him "I am not good at English, I will try my best to guide you" or "I am sorry if you find my english unhelpful"

Comment: Did you possibly mean "unhelpful" rather than "uninteresting"?